# noflo how to save changes in noflo-ui at the server

Tags: save, noflo

i install **node + noflo** on my server and create a **.fbp**.
now i start the **ws server** for the **noflo-ui** with

```
node node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs --graph graphs/test1.fbp
```

now i get an **url for the ui**. there i can make changes. 
but this **changes are not saved back to the fbp file**.
if i stop the node i lose all changes.

> i not have seen any save button.
>   is there a method to save?

is it possible to run more then one fbp file without starting an new server every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to persist modified graphs and/or components directly to the server with [Flowhub](http://app.flowhub.io). However, for future use [the spec](http://noflojs.org/documentation/protocol/) already contains a `network:persist` capability that will be used for this.

In the meanwhile, it is best to do this via GitHub... push your changes to a git repository, then pull to server.

Comment: ok, my use case will not have access to the internet. may by i am able to implement this. I take a try :)

Answer (score 0):

When you open the *live mode URL* for the runtime changes are not persisted anywhere. But if you add the runtime to Flowhub (for instance manually using IP+port), then you can start a project and changes are automatically kept in your browser.
You can then export the graph as .json, or push to Github.

There is currently no way to go between "live mode" and "project mode".